Adjusting axes placement and line using Swift's Charts library
I've the following code, I would like to modify it to change the placement and display of axes, as outlined below.
Chart generation (Playground)
import SwiftUI
import Charts
import PlaygroundSupport

struct BarChartExample: View {
    let data = [
        ("A", "Z", 5),
        ("A", "Z", 5),
        ("B", "Z", 10),
        ("C", "Y", 7),
        ("D", "Y", 3),
        ("E", "Y", 12),
        ("B", "Y", 10),
        ("C", "X", 7),
        ("D", "X", 3),
        ("E", "X", 12)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(data, id: \.0) { item in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Category", item.0),
                    y: .value("Value", item.2),
                    stacking: .standard
                )
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Category", item.1))
            }
        }
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks {
                AxisTick(centered: true, length: 10, 
                         stroke: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                AxisValueLabel()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
        .padding()
    }
}

// Present the view in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(BarChartExample())

Results

Desired outcome


I would like to move y-axis to left hand side

Including scales


Modify colour of axes and show them as white thick lines (consistently with the provided visual)

I've tried playing with AxisGridLine and AxisTick but I can't arrive at the desired result.

try using
.chartYAxis {
    AxisMarks(position: .leading) 
}

EDIT-1:
Here is a possible approach to display the X and Y axis lines as shown in your
picture, using chartPlotStyle with overlay.
You will have to adjust the colors.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        BarChartExample()
    }
}

struct BarChartExample: View {
    let data = [
        ("A", "Z", 5),
        ("A", "Z", 5),
        ("B", "Z", 10),
        ("C", "Y", 7),
        ("D", "Y", 3),
        ("E", "Y", 12),
        ("B", "Y", 10),
        ("C", "X", 7),
        ("D", "X", 3),
        ("E", "X", 12)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(data, id: \.0) { item in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Category", item.0),
                    y: .value("Value", item.2),
                    stacking: .standard
                )
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Category", item.1))
            }
        }
        
        // the axis lines
        .chartPlotStyle { plotArea in
            plotArea
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.red)
                        .frame(height: 8)
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.red)
                        .frame(width: 8)
                }
        }

        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .leading)
        }

        .padding()
    }
}


This moved the axis marks correctly but how can I force drawing of the axis white line?

updated my answer to show how to draw the axis lines.
